# Changing session variables in PHP page with if and else

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I want to change session variables according to the form submitted.

```
ob_start();
session_id("oneway");
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['oneway_book'])) {


  $_SESSION["source_oneway"] = $_POST['oneway_source'];
  $_SESSION["dest1"] = $_POST['oneway_destinations'];
  $_SESSION["date1"] = $_POST['oneway_date'];
  $_SESSION["time1"] = $_POST['oneway_time'];
  header('Location: new.php?oneway');
  # code...
}

elseif (isset($_POST['twoway_submit'])) {


  $_SESSION["source_oneway"] = $_POST['twoway_source'];
  $_SESSION["dest1"] = $_POST['twoway_destinations'];
  $_SESSION["date1"] = $_POST['twoway_date1'];
  $_SESSION["time1"] = $_POST['twoway_time1'];
  $_SESSION["date21"] = $_POST['twoway_date2'];
  $_SESSION["time21"] = $_POST['twoway_time2'];
  header('Location: new.php?roundtrip');
  # code...
}
```

The problem is I am getting proper session variables displayed for "one way" but I am getting empty variables for elseif condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `$_POST['twoway_submit']` is never set and thus your elseif is not executed?
Have you tried debugging it with [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)?

Or maybe `$_POST['oneway_book']` is always set so the elseif block is never executed?

Comment: Its working ,I had issues with jquery date picker plugin ,now its working ! hanks about xdebug ,it was helpful :)